# is wall a roof kick sits on considered a load bearing or just the area that is directly below it?

Tags: load

I have a bathroom wall that has my sink drain and faucet lines. The vent goes straight up. I want to insert a recessed mirror that would require me to make the vent to go around the mirror. The wall goes perpendicular over the underneath support beams and parallel with ceilings/roof truss. The ceiling truss come together on wall that is perpendicular to wall I am referring to but a roof kicker is resting on this wall(the one I want to put the mirror in). The kicker is about 4' from the vent pipe and more from mirror I want to install. Is this wall still considered a load bearing or just the area directly under the kikers. The area of wall the kickers rest on is right on top of a support beam under house.

Comment: Almost all exterior walls are load bearing. Don't remove or cut studs unless you plan to frame out a proper header.

Comment: The wall I am referring to is a interior wall

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Get the blueprints or consult a structural engineer.